# How to apply new css on text change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I am able to change the text using useState(), seeking for help on dynamically updating the CSS of changed text.

JS:

```
const [verifyAttendance, setViewAttendance] = useState("Verify Class Attendance")

<div className="verify-class-attendance">
  <span onClick={() => setViewAttendance('View Attendance')}>{verifyAttendance}</span>
  <ForwardArrow />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
verify-class-attendance {
     background-color: #f8f8f8;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     align-items: center;
     height: 51px;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: 600;
     color: #fc8b4c;
     letter-spacing: 0.5px;
     padding-left: 35px;
     padding-right: 35px;
     position: relative;
     top: -16px;
     margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
```

Comment: You can pass className as props

Comment: Based on the state, assign a different className to the component you want to style. That way you will be able to change the styling

Comment: Side note: The selector in your CSS is missing a `.` in front of it: `.verify-class-attendance`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use className as a state

```
const [verifyAttendance, setViewAttendance] = useState("Verify Class Attendance")
const [dynamicClassName, setDynamicClassName] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  setDynamicClassName({
    'View Attendance': 'view-attendance',
    'Verify Class Attendance': 'verify-class-attendance'
  }[verifyAttendance])
}, [verifyAttendance])

<div className={dynamicClassName}>
  <span onClick={() => setViewAttendance('View Attendance')}>{verifyAttendance}</span>
  <ForwardArrow />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do :

```
<div className=`${booleanState} ? "verify-class-attendance" : "other-css"`></div>
```

You would use the new state just like you did with the previous one